# minishift start with error in firewall rules with kvm

Tags: debian, openshift, kvm, openshift-origin, minishift

I'm tryng to start the VM with minishift but at the minishift start I've got this error

```
    root@Z32GB:~# minishift start
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'kvm' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if KVM driver is installed ...
   Driver is available at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm ...
   Checking driver binary is executable ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt is installed ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt default network is present ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt default network is active ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'kvm' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM ..... FAIL E1122 14:35:46.689655   22958 start.go:494] Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "virError(Code=1, Domain=59, Message='internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table filter --insert LIBVIRT_INP --in-interface virbr1 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n')". Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "virError(Code=1, Domain=59, Message='internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table filter --insert LIBVIRT_INP --in-interface virbr1 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n')"
```

my server is debian testing with KVM

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to update minishift using:
`minishift update`
After that do a clear cache:
`minishift delete --clear-cache`
Try to start again minishift and see if works.

Comment: I've done what you wrote and thi is the result:  https://pastebin.com/ghTBn1Mj